# Can't set Windows Terminal as default because it is not detected in the list of terminals

Tags: default-settings, windows-11, windows-terminal

I am running Windows 11 stable version on my Lenovo S340 since upgrading from Windows 10.

I looked in the settings of Windows Terminal to set it as the default application, but the list of terminal apps only contains Windows Console Host. The same is the case in the Terminal Settings section in the stock settings app. Typing cmd into run still opens the old Command Prompt window of its own.

I tried reinstalling Windows Terminal but to no avail.

[Selecting default terminal in the Settings app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0muf.png)

[Setting default from the Windows Terminal settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCHNh.png)

Answer (score 0):

A few things that I'm aware of that will cause this not to work properly:

- This feature only became available in the public Windows Terminal release a few days before your post, but I do assume that you have updated to the latest Store release before asking this.  However, you may want to double-check your Windows Terminal release (via the "About" dialog).  This feature does require [v1.11.2921.0](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.11.2921.0) or later.
- As mentioned in the release notes, this feature will only work when Windows Terminal is installed via the Microsoft Store or Appx.
- There is an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/10594) that I'm experiencing where this version does not work in a VM.  I believe this is a fairly isolated case, but you may want to have a look just in case this is the issue you are seeing.