# Change default Windows Terminal from Powershell to Command Prompt in Windows 11

Tags: windows-11

I cannot change the default Windows Terminal from Powershell to Command Prompt.
When click SETTINGS, it does not go to the option page to choose Command Prompt. Can anyone know how to resolve this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very weird. My windows allows me to change it. we seem to have a different version though, as the display of the options is visibly very different. what version of windows 11 is installed? Is it a private pc or company-owned?

Comment: Also - maybe this will help - https://superuser.com/questions/1683368/cant-set-windows-terminal-as-default-because-it-is-not-detected-in-the-list-of?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

When you click Settings in the Windows Terminal it tries to open the .json configuration file in a text editor
[image]

Since the .json file type isn't associated on your computer with any application, the "How do you want to open this file?" pop-up appears.

Click on **More apps** and select any text editor (Notepad should be good.)

Or rather update your Windows version as well as your Windows Terminal version (if it's not automatically updated with Windows) since nowadays the settings page is already updated not to be simply text editing a .json file:
[image]

Comment: If this doesn’t work, run “Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.SecHealthUI -AllUsers | Reset-AppxPackage”, and replace “Microsoft.SecHealthUI” with package name for Windows Terminal

Comment: Do you mean like this  Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.SecHealthUI -AllUsers | Reset-AppxPackage”, and replace “Windows Terminal”

Answer (score 2):

The normal method for changing the default profile in
Windows Terminal is:

- Open Windows Terminal
- Click the drop-down icon and select Settings
- In the Startup section, set "Default profile" to
  "Command Prompt".
- Click "Save" and restart Windows Terminal.

---

The fact that this method does not work is worrying and should
be treated. Some advice is given here.

**General troubleshooting**

- Run `chkdsk`. If any errors are found, mind your backups and
  then run `chkdsk /f`
- Test Windows integrity by running the commands:

  - [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
  - [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)

If errors are found when running DISM or SFC, return Windows to
a known state by doing
[Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/)

**Reinstall Windows Terminal from github**

Download the latest Windows Terminal from the
[microsoft / terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal)
project page.

Download the `.msixbundle` bundle, double-click it and then
click on the "Install" button in the wizard window.

If you encounter a problem with installing the bundle,
see the article
[How to Install MSIXBundle on Windows 10/11](https://www.minitool.com/news/install-msixbundle-windows.html)
for alternate methods of installation.